# How to rerun a program in Python IDLE within the shell?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, python-idle, hotkeys

How do i rerun a program in IDLE shell without having to go back to the saved code and pressing F5 over and over every time I want to execute it? is there any shortcuts or hotkeys that could be pressed while in the shell?

for example i have a simple program that prints a typed message:

```
message = input('Enter message: ')
print(message)
```

once i run this simple program, i give the input, the program prints input and the program ends. Now, say i want to give a different input, i'd have to leave the shell and go back to the saved code and press F5 again. but if there was a hotkey that could be pressed while in the shell that would rerun the program, that would be awesome.

Comment: Not currently, though it could be considered.  What is your use case?  For development, people usually edit before re-running.  To test multiple inputs, people usually use an input loop: `while True: val = input('prompt '); ...` or write an loop processing either pre-determined or random inputs.

Comment: Looping is a way but that would require me to add an unnecessary step to the code (the while loop), I was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut (like pressing F5 would run the program) that could be pressed to re-run the program for testing.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add `input()` in the end of your code so you can see the results in console before it disappear

Comment: Since Abdallah did not say that disappearing output was the problem, this should be a comment.